# How do you print value passed in provider as an output in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
provider "aws" {
    access_key = abc
    secret_key = abc
    region = abc
}
```

What would be the syntax to print "access_key"

```
output "access_key" {
    value = 
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @luk2302 I'm getting an error despite passing in values of a user with AdministratorAccess: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: operation error STS: GetCallerIdentity, net/http: invalid header field value "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential={access-key}\r/20220920/us-east-1/sts/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature={signature} for key Authorization

Comment: I don't think that is related to any credentials. Something else is wrong, not sure what. But that error is very obscure.

Comment: Please note that this post is an XY-problem, you ask for something but what you actually want is something entirely different. Now you got an answer trying to answer the question but not remotely solving the actual problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can't reference provider value. But you can reference a variable in both provider value and output, so just:

```
# variables.tf
access_key = "abc"

# main.tf
provider "aws" {
    access_key = var.access_key
    secret_key = ...
    region = ...
}

output "access_key" {
    value = var.access_key
}
```